# Match all nodes related to only two specific nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have 100 nodes with label A, and 2 nodes of label B. All nodes with label A are related to at least one node with label B. How do I get all nodes of label A related to both nodes of label B? I've tried the following method:

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[:TYPE]->(b:B) where b.Name = 'XYZ' or b.Name = 'ABC'
RETURN p
```

This only gives me all nodes related to either of these two nodes.

Edit: I've managed to do this by using the following query:

```
MATCH (a:A)- [:TYPE] ->(t:Type) where t.Name = 'ABC'
MATCH (a:A)- [:TYPE] -> (u:Type) where u.Name = 'XYZ'
return a, t, u
```

Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's several ways to do this.

If the :TYPE relationship on :A nodes only connects to :B nodes, and there is only ever one :TYPE relationship between each :A and :B node, then the fastest way is filter based on the degree of :TYPE relationships from :A nodes:

```
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE SIZE((a)-[:TYPE]->()) = 2
RETURN a
```

If :TYPE relationships go to more than just :B nodes, then you can change the query slightly. It won't quite be as efficient, but it will work fine:

```
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE SIZE((a)-[:TYPE]->(:B)) = 2
RETURN a
```

If the number of :B nodes increases, and you want to find :A nodes that connect to all :B nodes, then we can use collections as well as the ALL() function to get the right set of :A nodes:

```
MATCH (b:B)
WITH COLLECT(b) as bnodes
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE ALL(b in bnodes WHERE (b)<-[:TYPE]-(a))
RETURN a
```

And if you only need a subset of :B nodes, instead of all, then you can filter your initial match based on a collection of ids:

```
// assuming you supply a list parameter of ids called 'ids'
MATCH (b:B)
WHERE b.id in {ids}
WITH COLLECT(b) as bnodes
WITH HEAD(bnodes) as first, bnodes
MATCH (a)-[:TYPE]->(first)
WHERE ALL(b in TAIL(bnodes) WHERE (b)<-[:TYPE]-(a))
RETURN a
```

There's a bit of extra logic in there to only consider :A nodes that are types of one of the elements in your bnodes. That way we never consider :A nodes that aren't related to any of your bnodes, saving us from performing unnecessary comparisons.

Comment: This is a fantastic response, more than what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully that will help if you run into any of those other situations!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:TYPE]->(b:B) where b.Name = 'XYZ'
MATCH (a)-[:TYPE]->(b1:b) where b1.Name = 'ABC'
RETURN a
```

You cannot have a single `MATCH` query here,because filtering on one node with 2 different names will not work. Note also that you can assign variables to entities example `(a:A)` and return them  or do further operations as you like.